# OS X: directory access stalls; how to delete the directory?

Tags: macos, mac

There is a directory on my (solid-state) drive on OS X (Lion) that makes the computer stall when I try to delete or otherwise access it (no processor or drive activity).   What can be attempted so as to delete the directory?

Here is what I tried:

- Simply putting the directory in the trash and emptying the trash makes the Finder stall.
- Using `rm -Rf en.lproj` in a Terminal also stalls (`en.lproj` is the directory in question; it comes from Microsoft Office 2008); the command cannot be interrupted with Ctrl-C, Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z.
- Repairing the disk permissions and verifying the disk with Disk Utility does not help with the above two approaches.

Any other idea would be much appreciated!

PS: I guess that the directory contains files, but I can't see them either the Finder or with Unix commands (`ls en.lproj` stalls too).

Answer (score 0):

OK, there was a more robust way to try to remove this file, and it worked: I booted the computer in [single-user mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1492) (Apple-S), checked the disk with `/sbin/fsck -fy` and mounted it as a writable disk with `/sbin/mount -uw /` (as indicated in the messages printed in single-user mode).  Removing the directory with `rm -R` (as usual) worked.

I would guess that for some reason, the files in the directory that could not be otherwise removed were (unduly) used by some program, which made the computer stall…